# extract lines between two same delimiters ( multi instances delimiters)

Tags: linux, awk, sed

What I want is from the first occurrence of the delimiter to the last occurrence of the same delimiter,including everything between them,the delimiter may appear multi-times in a log file.
[image]

sample.log

```
[T=iaaaaaaaaa134]:SampleClass9: 
[T=iaaaaaaaaa134]:SampleClass7: 
[T=iaaaaaaaaa134]:SampleClass3: 
[T=iaaaaaaaaa134]:SampleClass1: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass1: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass2: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass3: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass4: 
Exception:NullPointerException:
    sampte 1
    sampte 1
    sampte 1
    sampte 1
    sampte 1
    
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass00: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass00: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass00: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass00: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass00: 
Exception:NullPointerException2:
    sampte 2
    sampte 2
    sampte 2
    sampte 2
    sampte 2
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass12: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass32: 
[T=i8732jddcd234]:SampleClass22: 
[T=2eeeeeeeee234]:SampleClass32: 
[T=2eeeeeeeee234]:SampleClass82: 
[T=2eeeeeeeee234]:SampleClass22: 
[T=2eeeeeeeee234]:SampleClass22:
```

for example: I want to extract the lines starting from the first occurrence of **i8732jddcd234** (the delimiter) to the latest occurrence of **i8732jddcd234** and everything between them. possibly with awk, sed, grep linux command.because this is a log file on linux server.
I tried with

```
awk /'i8732jddcd234','i8732jddcd234'/ test.log
```

of course, it won't work

Comment: @RavinderSingh123 Can you explain why this was undeleted and reopened? It seems to have very little redeeming value, and arguably a duplicate of a common FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee, Sorry I didn't get this comment's notification(since I was not tagged properly). With respect to link which is added as a dupe doesn't looked to me exact one so I voted to open, for low quality IMHO OP has shown efforts in question so I voted to reopen, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be dupe of the linked question. This problem is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/i8732jddcd234/{if(!first){first=FNR};end=FNR} {a[FNR]=$0} END{for(i=first;i<=end;i++){print a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/i8732jddcd234/ {
   if (!first) {
      first = FNR
   }
   end = FNR
}
{
   a[FNR] = $0
}
END {
  for(i = first; i <= end; i++) {
     print a[i]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
last=$(nl sample.log | tac | awk '/i8732jddcd234/ {print $1; exit}')
sed -n "/i8732jddcd234/,${last}p" sample.log
```

or, with awk taking 2 passes through the file:

```
awk -v code=i8732jddcd234 '
    NR == FNR {
        if ($0 ~ code) {
            if (!first) first=FNR
            last=FNR
        }
        next
    } 
    first <= FNR && FNR <= last
' sample.log sample.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/i8732jddcd234/!d;:a;n;:b;//ba;$d;N;bb' file
```

Delete all lines till there is one containing `i8732jddcd234`. Print the line containing `i8732jddcd234` and then check to see if the following line does too and if so repeat. Otherwise, gather up the lines until the next occurrence of `i8732jddcd234` or the end-of-file, in which case the accumulated lines can be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

shell only...

```
    #!/bin/bash

    fileLength=`wc -l dat | cut -d' ' -f1`

    firstMatch=0
    lastMatch=0

    for i in `grep -n i8732jddcd234 dat | cut -d: -f1`; do
        if [ $firstMatch == 0 ] ; then
            firstMatch=$i
        else
            lastMatch=$i
        fi
    done

    diff=$(( lastMatch - firstMatch ))
    topOfMatch=$(( fileLength - firstMatch ))

    tail --lines=$topOfMatch dat | head --lines=$diff
```